# ggplot: assign color to value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data from survey question ranging from 1 to 5 (degree of agreement).
I need to create a plot for different groups. The colors should range from dark-red (1) to dak-green (5).

```r
palette <- c("#0da262", "#62d5a4", "gray", "#e07171", "#d34040")
```

However, as the groups are pretty small it might happen that not all possible values from 1 to 5 appear in the data (run the code repeatedly). For example it might happen, that in one group there were no answers `1`, so that the first color `(#0da262)` should not be used. It should start with the second color instead `(#62d5a4)`. How can a assign the colors to the values so that they always stay the same (i.e. 5 should always be dark red and 1 should always be dark gree, 3 should be gray etc.)?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 15

test_df <- data.frame(varA = sample(1:5, size=n, replace=TRUE),
                      #varB = sample(1:5, size=n, replace=TRUE),
                      grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = n, replace=TRUE))

palette <- c("#0da262", "#62d5a4", "gray", "#e07171", "#d34040")

test_df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("var")) %>%
  group_by(grp, name) %>%
  count(value) %>%
  mutate(percent = 1/sum(n)*n) %>%

ggplot(aes(x = name, y = percent, fill = as.factor(value))) + 
   geom_col(position = "fill") +
   coord_flip() +
   scale_fill_manual(values = palette, drop = FALSE) +
   labs(fill = "Value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your definition of `palette` in `setNames()`, like this:

```
palette <- setNames(c("#0da262", "#62d5a4", "gray", "#e07171", "#d34040"), as.character(1:5))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a data.frame with the index of color-value pairs, then join with the original data.frame.

In the call to ggplot, use `scale_fill_identitity()`:

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 15

test_df <- data.frame(varA = sample(1:5, size=n, replace=TRUE),
                      #varB = sample(1:5, size=n, replace=TRUE),
                      grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = n, replace=TRUE))

palette <- c("#0da262", "#62d5a4", "gray", "#e07171", "#d34040")
color_index <- setNames(1:5, palette) |> enframe(name = 'color')

test_df <- test_df |> 
    left_join(color_index, by =c ('varA' = 'value'))
```

**ggplot**

```
test_df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("var")) %>%
    group_by(grp, name, color) %>%
    count(value) %>%
    mutate(percent = 1/sum(n)*n) %>%
    
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = percent, fill = color)) + 
    geom_col(position = "fill") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_identity() +
    labs(fill = "Value")
```

[image]